# Circle-Polygon intersections

Tags: python, algorithm, fortran, computational-geometry

**A Computational Geometry problem:**
The point `P0` is chosen randomly on an edge (e.g.,`EB`) of a polygon (e.g.,`BCDE`), to find possible points (i.e., `P1,P2,P3,...`) on other edges based on the given distance (i.e., `r`). The following demonstration shows a solution by finding intersections between the circle centered on the point `P0` and the edges of polygon. So the problem basically could be solved by `Circle--Line-Segment` intersection analysis.

I wonder **is there any more efficient method** for this very simple problem in terms of computation cost? The process will be evaluated several `million times` so any improvemnt is of interest.

- the final solution will benefit from **Python** power;
- the core computation will be in **Fortran** if required.

[image]

**Updates:**
Thanks for your comments. Please consider my comments on comments which helps to clarify the question more. Not willing to repeat them here, encouraging to consider all comments and answers ;).

I just implemented the method of `Circle--Line-Segment Intersection` based on the algorithm found [[here]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html). Actually I adapted it to work with line-segments. The benchmark of the algorithm implemented in Python is as follows:
[image]
[image]
The number of line segments is: `100,000` and the system is usual desktop. The elapsed time is: `15 seconds`. Hope these are helpful to give some idea of computation cost. Implementation of core in **Fortan** could improve the performance significantly.
However the translation is the last step.

Comment: Is the distance `r` of all million queries the same? Can we count on the polygon to be convex?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev For our problem all polygons are convex. `r` could vary for each iteration so it could be varying but is constant for each polygon individually.

Comment: And are the millions of queries done in a single polygon or in different?

Comment: You forgot to mark one intersection, to the left of P1, in the picture

Comment: The original problem is in `3D`. It is possible so projecting each 3D polygon on `XY` plane therefore the possible solutions for the `2D` case as questioned here will be useful for '3D'. However I guess sometimes some solutions are more straightforward or perhaps more efficient in `3D` compared to the its extended verion based on `2D` solutions.

Comment: @Wesley That is by purpose. The interest is intersections not on the same edge of the point.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev There are millions of polygons, for each according to the vector of **`r`** (many radii) an `r` chosen and the process proceeds.

Comment: @Developer I couldn't understand this part sorry: `for each according to the vector of r (many radii) an r chosen and the process proceeds`

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I meant that suppose you have `10 million polygons`. Also you have `10 million r` values. So each polygon has a target `r` value. So we are looking to find all intersections between circles centered on a point on polygons (chosen randomly) and polygons. That is there is only one circle per polygon.

Comment: @Developer Your 2D-3D assumption only holds if the points in the polygon are coplanar, and if the axis of projection is perpendicular to that plane.

Comment: @Developer Meaning, in short, that you can only project along the Z-axis and the polygon has to be parallel to the XY-plane or your assumption won't work.

Comment: @toon81 Actually the points (vertices) are coplanar for each polygon for our specific case. Your point however is important for the extension of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For intersection between `line` (or `line-segment`) and a `circle` (`sphere` in `3D`) there is a bit more explanation, implementation details and also **Python, C** etc sample codes in [[**this link**]](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/sphereline/). You may try them for your problem.
The idea is basically the same as you have already found in [[here]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html).

Comment: I wish you would've written the answer in your actual answer instead of linking to it. It's ten years later and the link is broken. :§

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `circle--line-intersection` is optimized, you might be able to gain something by distinguishing between different cases:

for point A, B:

- If d(P0, A) < r and d(P0, B) < r: No intersection
- if d(P0, A) == r: Intersection at A
- if d(P0, B) == r: Intersection at B
- If d(P0, A) < r and d(P0, B) > r: 1 intersection, execute `circle--line-intersection`
- If d(P0, A) > r and d(P0, B) < r: 1 intersection, execute `circle--line-intersection`
- If d(P0, A) > r and d(P0, B) > r: There is either 0, 1 or 2 intersections
  -> If the [minimum distance](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/) to line (A, B) > r: No intersections
  -> If the [minimum distance](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/) to line (A, B) == r: 1 intersection
  -> If the [minimum distance](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/) to line (A, B) < r: 2 intersections

Comment: In the last case I believe you meant d(P0, P2) > r.

Comment: Note that the circle centered on `P0`, so all intersections lie on the circle and so their distances are equal to `r`. That is `d(P0,*)=r`. Am I missing something from your answer?

Comment: Sorry I confused the intersections with the actual points.. I'll fix the answer, hopefully it makes more sense then

Comment: last case should be d(P0, A) > r and d(P0, B) > r and it can have either 0, 1 (tangent) or 2 intersections